# Overloading __setattr__ causing AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that stores a variable, and then should call be able to execute a given piece of code, passed as an argument, whenever that variable is changed to a specified value.  I am trying to do that like this:

```
class SharedAttribute(object):    
    def __init__(self, value, onEquals={}):
        self.value = value
        self.onEquals = onEquals

    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        super(SharedAttribute, self).__setattr__(key, val)  #Set the attribute to the new value

        if key == "value":  #If the attribute being changed is the value attribute:
            if val in self.onEquals:  #If the new value is something that should cause something to happen:
                if type(self.onEquals[val]) == str:  #If there's only one command:
                    exec(self.onEquals[val])  #execute it

                elif type(self.onEquals[val]) == tuple:  #If there's a tuple of commands:
                    for eachFunction in self.onEquals[value]:  #Execute each of them
                        exec(eachFunction)
```

It would be instantiated like so:

```
foo = SharedAttribute(0, onEquals = {1: 'doSomething(arguments)', 2: ('doAnotherThing()', 'yetAnotherThing(arguments)'})
```

When I try to create an instance of the class, it gives me

```
AttributeError: 'SharedAttribute' object has no attribute 'onEquals'.
```

I thought that it was because `if val in self.onEquals` was trying to access `onEquals` while `onEquals` was being defined, because it was calling `__setattr__` to define it, but I added the `if key == "value":`, and it's still acting up.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `__setattr__` is also called for `self.value = value` in `__init__` and then accessing not defined yet `self.onEquals`.

You can try changing order of `self.value` and `self.onEquals` lines in `__init__` as suggested.

But if you don't want to run functions from `onEquals` when instantiating the class, leave the order as it is and check if `onEquals` is already set in `__setattr__` like:

```
def __setattr__(self, key, val):
    super(SharedAttribute, self).__setattr__(key, val)

    if key == "value" and getattr(self, "onEquals", False):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`__setattr__` is called for *every* access to save an attribute.  When `SharedAttribute`'s `__init__()` runs neither `self.value` nor `self.onEquals` exist yet, but `__setattr__` will try to acess `self.onEquals` when it is setting `self.value` -- because you have `self.value` being set first.

So you have a couple different ways to solve this:

- swap the two lines in your `__init__` function, or
- have a dummy class variable `onEquals` set to an empty `dict`

The first solution is the quickest and easiest; the second solution has some risk that you will inadvertently access the class version of `onEquals` and then have a hard to track down bug to figure out.